# Programs and procedure for Blackwood test?

Tags: biostatistics

I am looking for programs and procedure for the Bradley-Blackwood test, which is normally used to assess test-retest reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This presumably means the work of

Bradley, E. L. and L. G. Blackwood. 1989. Comparing paired data:  A simultaneous test for means and variances. *American Statistician* 43: 234-235.

A Stata implementation is included in `concord` (`search concord` to find download sources and select the most recent).